# Как сделать exe с cmd с помощью команды в windows?

Tags: windows, cmd

Как сделать exe с cmd с помощью команды в windows?
Что-то типо такого:

```
file.exe name_file.cmd console=False
```

`file.exe` - программа которая из cmd компелирует exe
`name_file.cmd` - скрипт
`console=False` - аргемент, будет ли открываться окно или нет